# How to create quantiles in R and plot histogram

Tags: r, histogram, percentile, quantile

I have recently started working with R. I have a dataset which is composed of two columns and 100000 rows as shown below:

```
       Y    TOTA
1      1    403500.000
2      1    188334.000
3      0    812387.000
4      0    163626.000
5      1    49527.000
6      1    48661.000
7      0    36712.000
8      1    31745.000
9      1    23342.000
10     0    46835.000
...... .    .........
100000 0    10.982
```

The variable Y can have just two values: 0 or 1, whereas the variable TOTA can have various values.
The function summary gives me the following result:

```
          Y               TOTA         
  Min.   :0.0000   Min.   :       0  
  1st Qu.:0.0000   1st Qu.:     939  
  Median :1.0000   Median :    3918  
  Mean   :0.5113   Mean   :   40245  
  3rd Qu.:1.0000   3rd Qu.:   11028  
  Max.   :1.0000   Max.   :18938000  
                   NA's   :261
```

**AIM:**

I would like to create a table with 10 rows and 3 columns. Each row represents a decile of my dataset and the last one shows NAs. Now I would like to populate my table looking at the dataset. If the first column in the dataset is **1**  then add +1 to the created table where the value matches the value range of one of the columns and the column "Number Active Companies". If the first value is **0** then add +1 in the column of "Number Passive Companies" in the respective row where the value matches the table value ranges.
Each row of the table represents a different range for the variable TOTA

**WHAT I HAVE ATTEMPTED**

What I have tried so far is to create a table which will contain the result of my dataset processing

```
    Number Active Companies  Number Passive Companies   Total
1   0                       0                           0
2   0                       0                           0
3   0                       0                           0
4   0                       0                           0
5   0                       0                           0
6   0                       0                           0
7   0                       0                           0
8   0                       0                           0
9   0                       0                           0
10  0                       0                           0



result<-matrix(data = 0, nrow = 10, ncol = 3, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = list(1:10,c("Number Active Companies","Number Passive Companies","Total")));
```

Afterwards I have created 10 groups which contain different range of my variable:

```
x > 0 && x < 100
x > 100 && x < 1000
x > 1000 && x < 10000
x > 10000 && x < 100000
x > 100000 && x < 1000000
x > 1000000 && x < 1000000
x > 5938000 && x < 10938000
x > 10938000 && x < 15938000
x > 15938000 && x < 18938000
x=NA
```

Now I would like to populate the previous table in this way.
I want to analyse each row of the Y variable if it is 1 it should add 1 to the column number active companies and in the row in which the number belong to anc the same when Y is zero.

```
    for(i in TOTA){
    if (Y=1)
          if(x > 0 && x < 100){
          }else if(x > 100 && x < 1000){
          }else if(x > 1000 && x < 10000){
          }else if(x > 10000 && x < 100000){
          }else if(x > 100000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 1000000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 1000000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 5938000 && x < 10938000){
          }else if( x > 10938000 && x < 15938000){      
          }else if( x > 15938000 && x < 18938000) {
          }else{
           //Nas
          } 
    }else if(Y=0){

          if(x > 0 && x < 100){
          }else if(x > 100 && x < 1000){
          }else if(x > 1000 && x < 10000){
          }else if(x > 10000 && x < 100000){
          }else if(x > 100000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 1000000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 1000000 && x < 1000000){
          }else if( x > 5938000 && x < 10938000){
          }else if( x > 10938000 && x < 15938000){      
          }else if( x > 15938000 && x < 18938000) {
          }else{
           //Nas
          } 
    }
```

**QUESTIONS**

How can I write in the table?
How can I do this process in a easier manner?
How can I create an histogram of this table?

I am wondering whether I am doing the right thing, given the fact I have read the manual for the functions quantile() and percentile() and it seems they do the same thing

Can you please give me some guideline and possibly some commands to achieve my aim

Thank you

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, but see if something like `table(cut(dataset$TOTA[dataset$Y == 0],  c(0, 100, 1000, ...)))` helps. (and a second time with `Y == 1`)

Comment: Your code is dangerously close to qualifying for thedailywtf.com :-( . Any time you have more than two `else`, it's pretty much guaranteed there's a far better way to sort or split datasets.  Here I might consider  `hist(log(data))`

Comment: You say you want deciles of your dataset, but the breaks you propose (0,100,1000,...) will not do that. So which is it? Do you want these breaks, or do you want deciles?

Comment: @CarlWitthoft Thank you Carl! Yes it is pretty much what I was thinking. I am sure there is a more straightforward way of doing it

Comment: @jlhoward Thank you! I would like to brake my dataset values in 10 groups. I have created this algorithm because I do not how to divide my dataset in R and assign each value to a different categories. In addition to my categories there is one extra group which is for NAs (Missing values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still difficult to figure out what you are trying to accomplish, but this is my best guess:

```
# create reproducible example - you already have this...
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Y=sample(0:1,100000,replace=T),
                 TOTA=runif(100000,0,18938000))
na     <- sample(1:100000,5000)    # 5% NA
df[na,]$TOTA <- NA

# you start here...
breaks <- c(0,10^(2:6), 5938000, 10938000, 15938000, 18938000)
labels <- c("0-100","100-1000","1000-10000","10000-100000",
            "100000-100000","100000-1000000","1000000-5938000",
            "5938000-10938000","10938000-18938000","NA")
df$group <- cut(df$TOTA,breaks=breaks,labels=F)
df[is.na(df$group),]$group <- 10
df$grpLabel <- labels[df$group]

result           <- aggregate(Y~group,df,function(x)sum(x==1))
colnames(result) <- c("Group","Active")
result$Passive   <- aggregate(Y~group,df,function(x)sum(x==0))$Y
result$Group     <- labels[result$Group]
result
#                Group Active Passive
# 1              0-100      0       1
# 2           100-1000      1       2
# 3         1000-10000     29      17
# 4       10000-100000    224     212
# 5      100000-100000   2310    2288
# 6     100000-1000000  12365   12328
# 7    1000000-5938000  12508   12522
# 8   5938000-10938000  12526   12649
# 9  10938000-18938000   7485    7533
# 10                NA   2544    2456
```

So this divides the dataset into groups using `cut(...)`, then sums the `1s` and `0s` separately using `aggregate(...)`, then labels the groups. Normally you could use `cut(...)` without `labels=F` and get meaningful labels for your groups directly. The problem here is that `aggregate(...)` will sort these alphabetically, which is not what you want.

Also, note that in your question you have a range 1000000 - 1000000 (e.g 1MM to 1MM). I assumed this is supposed to be 1000000 - 5938000.